# What's different between the two sentences?

Tags: differences, sentence, tenses, construction

Hey,
I'm watching a TV show, and there's a sentence:

> I knew giving you that book was gonna come back and bite me in the ass.

Can I change it to:

> I know gave you that book was gonna come back and bite me in the ass.

Comment: You *can* change it to that, but, it would be grammatically incorrect then... `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The phrase "giving you that book" is the subject of the clause.

Comment: +1 The clause is "[Subject] was gonna come back and bite me in the ass.", where [Subject] is "giving you that book".

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are thinking that "knew giving" is some funny sort of compound verb, and wanting to move the past tense within it; but that's not how the sentence is structured. 
There is an omitted "that" (which can often be done in colloquial English), so the structure is:

"I knew [that [giving you that book] was ... ]"

Answer (score 0):

I think most of us are inclined to say that "gave" makes the sentence ungrammatical. However, from a linguistic standpoint, we probably all understood what was meant, so it doesn't really matter which is used.

Comment: If I met the second sentence without the context of the first sentence to explain it, I would have a very hard time figuring out what was going on.  Also I am very opposed to the idea that "as long as it's understandable it doesn't matter if it's 'right' or not."  Saying it right makes it much more understandable.